# What are these creatures on the cover of Kane Chronicles: The Throne of Fire?

Tags: object-identification, mythology, the-kane-chronicles

What are these two creatures?

[image: Kane Chronicles: The Throne of Fire]

I feel that they could be either *tjesu heru*,

> Sure enough, Menshikov's staff began to writhe and grow.
>
> *Great*, I thought. *Another serpent*.
>
> But something was wrong with this one. Instead of a tail, it had a head on both ends. At first I thought we'd caught some luck, and Menshikov had summoned a monster with a rare genetic birth defect. Then the thing sprouted four dragon legs. Its body grew until it was the size of a draught horse, curved like a U, with mottled red and green scales and a rattlesnake head on either side. It reminded me of that two-headed animal from Doctor Dolittle. You know - the pushmi-pullyu? Except Doctor Dolittle would never have wanted to talk to this thing, and, if he had, it would probably have said just *Hello, I'm going to eat you*.

or the serpopards.

> “Longnecks,” Carter said incredulously. “Sadie, did you see those things?”
>
> I couldn’t find an answer. Then one of the creatures was thrown out of the pool. It slammed into the doors right in front of us, and I jumped back in alarm. On the other side of the glass was the most terrifying animal I’d ever seen. Its body was like a leopard’s—lean and sinewy, with golden spotted fur—but its neck was completely wrong. It was green and scaly and at least as long as the rest of its body. It had a cat’s head, but no normal cat’s. When it turned its glowing red eyes towards us, it howled, showing a forked tongue and fangs dripping with green venom.

> We examined the back of the stone, and I had to admit I was impressed by Carter's memory. Two cat-snake monsters stood in the centre of the palette, their necks entwined. On either side, Egyptian men with ropes were trying to capture the creatures.
>
> 'They're called serpopards,' Carter said. 'Serpent leopards.'

The *tjesu heru* appears in *The Throne of Fire*, but the serpopards are from *The Red Pyramid*. To me, the serpopards seem to fit the cover, but they're from the wrong book, which doesn't make sense.

Is there any other canon evidence to identify the creatures?

Comment: From looking at the cover I'd say it's a giant version of an amphisbaena- a snake with a head on both ends.

Comment: @Nu'Daq The amphisbaena is Greek (one appears in Tower of Nero); the Kane Chronicles are Egyptian.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *tseju heru* make an appearance in the [official graphic novelisation](https://rickriordan.com/book/the-throne-of-fire-the-graphic-novel/).

Given the similarity in design, I think we can safely say that that (allowing for the usual [cover insanity](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/CoversAlwaysLie)) is what's being depicted on your book cover.

[image]

Comment: The *tjesu heru* is described as not having a tail though. This one clearly does. I guess we'd call that graphic novel insanity.